# Cannot upgrade Angular Material with Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8

I did everything described in [the update guide](https://update.angular.io/) (complex app) but it was keep failing at the point of `ng update @angular/material` with the following error:

```
Package "@angular/flex-layout" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/cdk" (requires "^7.0.0-rc.0", would install "8.0.0").
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root cause was that I **did not install the core packages prior to the update**.

`ng update @angular/cli @angular/core`

also, if you keep getting the error, might give a shot to `--force` flag to ignore peer dependency problems - but that won't necessary solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You need to update `@angular/cli` and `@angular/core` to the latest version of v8.

```
ng update @angular/core@8 @angular/cli@8 --force
```